# How To Catch A SQL Error That May Change With SQL Server Upgrades

Tags: c#, sql

I made a catch, that if a specific sql server error is thrown, that the code can dis-regard and carry on.  A co-worker said that the error message I'm catching is being thrown from SQL and it may change when we upgrade to 2008.  He said my solution will work today, but it is a weak solution.  So, my question is...How should I catch and handle a error thrown from SQL server, if it may be dependend on the sql server version. ie(2005, 2008 or newer)?  Any ideas on how to make the catch better?

My code

```
string sqlError = "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint Table1. The conflict occurred in database Work1, table Table2.";

catch (Exception oExp)
{
//This check will allow the specific error to continue without getting caught.
if (oExp.Message.Contains(Constants.sqlError) == false)
{
  throw oExp;
}
}
```

Comment: why is the error being thrown in the first place. i would try to resolve that.

Comment: Agreed - this is an avoidable error - so take steps to avoid the possibility of it happening.

Comment: and don't `throw oExp;` just `throw;` otherwise you'll lose the stack trace I think.

Comment: it may make sense to put the error handling logic in a stored procedure rather than in C# (one possible way of dealing with the problem as highlighted in Daniel & Evil's comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this *is* avoidable so you *should* do the right thing and make sure it can't happen in the first place.

And as you've surmised, using static text is a bad thing. This is even more true when you consider that these messages will change depending on the LANGUAGE that SQL Server is installed with or the user is logged on as (as SQL messages are locale sensitive), regardless of upgrade level.

Also ... I don't quite understand why you'd want to continue even if this error is thrown as it sounds like it puts your data into an inconsistent state, so I'd review whether you're doing the right thing in the first place. However I don't know your application...

So with all those caveats said ... in the event that avoiding this is not possible (for whatever reason - excluding laziness :-) ), rather than catch a generic `Exception`, you should catch a [`SqlException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx), which includes the `State` and `Number` properties which you should be able to use verbatim.

Comment: There was a project that deleted rows from the table and this error was unforeseen.  They don't have the rows they deleted from the table so, we can't restore.  Don't ask me why, I don't know.  I will look more into SqlException that deals with state and number as suggested by Chris J.  Thanks all.